# Has sombody already asked about setting up tabs correctly on another site

Tags: discussion

It seems like setting up tabs and its spacing in vim should be trivial but; but in IMO it is actually a non trivial task (to get all the settings correct and working together).

But I have not seen this question on vim site.
Is it covered well on another stack exchange site (that is why nobody asked here) or is it considered too trivial to even ask about?

As a new user to vim this was one of the first task I did but it took my forever to get all the setting working correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question/problem would be, exactly, but if you have a question or if you have useful information to share you should ask a question (& possible answer it yourself). However, you probably *don't* want to ask a question for the sake of asking a question. If it's covered well on other stack exchange sites, then it's already covered well. Also see this answer: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/15/51

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty safe bet that somebody, somewhere, has asked about configuring tabs in vim somewhere on StackExchange.

It is impossible for *us* to say if they have the same *specific* question(s) you do, so you should search StackOverflow or SuperUser for your question. If you don't find it, then you should absolutely ask it here.

Comment: Whether the question has been answered on any other site is [irrelevant](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/45/24).